# this is undefined in class

Tags: ecmascript-6, import, this, undefined

I have the following class

```
class ContractStore {

    clauses = [];

    addClause() {
        this.clauses.push({
            id: uuidv1()
        })
    }

}

export let contractStore = new ContractStore();
```

and then importing it as

```
import { contractStore } from '../store/ContractStore'
...
contractStore.addClause()
```

and I am getting `this` as `undefined` in `addClause()` method. what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing to set the context here. You can do it in two ways.

Arrow function way

```
class ContractStore {

    clauses = [];

    addClause = () => {
        this.clauses.push({
            id: uuidv1()
        })
    }

}
```

or 
Bind way

```
class ContractStore {
    constructor() {
      this.addClause = this.addClause.bind(this)
    }
    clauses = [];

    addClause() {
        this.clauses.push({
            id: uuidv1()
        })
    }

}
```

Thanks. Feedbacks are welcome